# What web font services are there?

Tags: web-fonts

As a small website building shop, I'm looking for some sort of agency account at a web font services to be able to pitch/show/stage typography in websites to potential customers. Used to have an agency account at fonts.com but doesn't seem to work anymore. What good web font services are there?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are generally poor questions for Stack sites.

Comment: >pitch/show/stage typography in websites to potential customers

Is it not your job to do that? You are the agency.

Comment: @Rafael - It is my job. I need acces to web-fonts to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first obvious option is Google fonts.

But in reality, it depends on what you think "What good web font services are there?" means.

If you want a website to export different TTF fonts to a variety of web-friendly formats to host them yourself, then probably fontawesome.com and fontsquirrel.com.

To show them to your client, you can simply have your font locally.